# Can not use BT Wifi with FON Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, connection

I've been trying to connect to BT Wifi with FON. It connects to the network but no login page shows and when it does its very slow and i can not get past it. My friend with a MAC is easily able to connect to BT Wifi with FON. We're literally in the same room. Here are the results from running the ubuntu wireless script : http://paste.ubuntu.com/24040417/

Comment: In order not to overwhelm the reader, please format the output of such script correctly, or post it [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) instead, and link it in your post :)

Comment: Update: connects to bt wifi with fon just fine now. just doesn't connect to bt wifi properly